# AngularJs $http post successCallback is causing the page to redirect even when the server responds with a 200 status

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have written a simple controller in agularjs which handles a form submission. The form is submitted using ng-submit.

The server is handling the post request successfully and returning an http status 200. 
But AngularJs is calling the current page url again using POST method which is causing the server to return MethodNotAllowedException (Laravel 5.2) page.

This is the controller code.

```
app.controller('adminAddController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Page', function($scope, $http, Page){
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.processForm = function($event) {

        console.log($scope.formData);
        $http({
            method  : "post",
            url     : 'http://localhost:8000/api/blogs',
            data    : $scope.formData,  
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Can you show your form element?

Comment: paste code of your form please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the problem was not as difficult to solve as it seemed.

I removed the action="" attribute from my form element and it started working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this occurs because you are not blocking the default action of the form so after your Ajax call is sent, the form does it's normal submit and then the browser either gets redirected or reloads the page based on the form submit.

If you add:

```
$event.preventDefault();
```

to your handler, that should take care of it.

```
app.controller('adminAddController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Page', function($scope, $http, Page){
    $scope.formData = {};
    $scope.processForm = function($event) {

        // prevent default form submission
        $event.preventDefault();

        console.log($scope.formData);
        $http({
            method  : "post",
            url     : 'http://localhost:8000/api/blogs',
            data    : $scope.formData,  
        })
        .then(function successCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
}]);
```

Also, [per the angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form), if your `<form>` element does not have an `action` attribute, the form submission will be blocked automatically by angular.  You did not show the relevant form HTML so we don't know if this applies in your case.

Answer (score 0):

**Try changing like this** :

```
app.controller('adminAddController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Page', function($scope, $http, Page){
        $scope.formData = {};
        $scope.processForm = function($event) {

            console.log($scope.formData);
            $http.post('api/blogs', {data:$scope.formData})
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
        };
    }]);
```

**Thanks & Cheers**

Comment: Why would this fix the problem?  Good answers usually should contain some explanation about what was changed and why, not just code.